# WCF with discovery fails with socket not valid in its context on XP?

Tags: c#, wcf, service-discovery

I'm trying to use WCF's discovery mechanism in .NET 4.0.  It works on Windows 7 but fails on an XP machine with a socket exception saying that "the requested address is not valid in its context" (the endpoint is soap.udp://239.255.255.250:3702).

Is the Windows 7 vs XP a red herring?  netstat doesn't seem to show any conflicts.  What am I missing here?

I've created a simplified test service that shows the problem using the following config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata/>
          <serviceDiscovery />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <endpointDiscovery />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloWorldService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Demo"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint kind="mexEndpoint" />
        <endpoint kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" />
        <endpoint contract="Test.IHelloWorld" 
                  address="/Hello" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue logged on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588067/wcf-discovery-feature-in-net-framework-cannot-be-used-in-windows-xp-sp-3). Unfortunately there is currently no workaround and Microsoft response is

> The exception you are mentioning is
>   normally hit when trying to bind the
>   socket to an IP address that isn't
>   valid. Can you please check this and
>   if possible try on a machine with a
>   different OS. There are currently no
>   known limitations of the WCF Discovery
>   feature on XP.

Comment: This looks uncomfortably like what I'm seeing.  This is probably the answer, but I'll hold off marking this as such, hoping for a happier ending!

Comment: @Russ: I hope you will get a solution to this... My feeling is there is a problem and MS will need to issue an HotFix. I suggest you to post on Microsoft Connect so at least another person will report the problem. Good luck :)

Comment: Not really an answer per se, but as good a lead as I'm probably going to get.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the XP machine behind a firewall or router? To be specific, does the address 239.255.255.250 really belong to the XP machine, or does it actually use a NAT address? Try running ipconfig to see what it thinks it has.

Comment: The XP machine is behind a router.  The machine's IP address (from ipconfig) is 192.168.1.104.  Not sure where you're going with this, but I'll try most anything!  I thought the 239.255.255.250 address was the well-known multi-cast addr for service discovery?

Comment: I'm not sure myself, actually, but it was a hunch. Although I don't think my answer is a real solution, if I had the same problem this would be my first lead.